# MySQL Return Column Types from Select Statement

Tags: mysql

Is is possible to get the column types and names from a `select` statement in `MySQL`?

E.g.,

```
SELECT t.first_col, t.third_col
FROM my_table t
WHERE t.id = 1
```

And then I would send that to `MySQL` and have it tell me.

```
column_name  |  type     | length
first_col    |  varchar  | 5
third_col    |  int      | null
```

I know I can do it in `SQL Server` I was hoping I can do it in `MySQL` too.

Answer (score 0):

Why is that Questions come in pairs?  This recent one discussed the solution you want:

[MySQL data precision confusion](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/184543/mysql-data-precision-confusion)

Comment: I'm actually looking to get the metadata of the query. Not table metadata.

Comment: Sorry, no such info.  `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` gives you some info, but not specifically what you asked for.

Comment: I saw that `MySQL` has support for `CTE`s so I thought maybe they would be able to support some type inference for a `SELECT` statement.